# Size of fixed position alerts in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a web page using Twitter Bootstrap with a "floating" (fixed-position) alert at the top, like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="top-message" class="container row col-sm-12">
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Hi there!
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- page content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top-message {
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs1f8u6j/)

On smaller screens, this works perfectly:

[image: On smaller screens]

However, on larger screens, the alert simply extends out like this:

[image: On larger screens]

Removing the `width: 100%` from `top-message` wouldn't be an option either, since I need the alert to occupy some width even though the text is small.

How should I design the page so that the alert is maintained in the middle of the page like in smaller screens; for any size of the screen on which the page is rendered?

Comment: the problem's your html structure I guess, why are you using a fixed element inside a column? put it before the closing tag of the body and it'll work much better

Comment: here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/zs1f8u6j/1/

Comment: @AminJafari Please turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem's your html structure I guess, why are you using a fixed element inside a column? put it before the closing tag of the body and it'll work much better. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zs1f8u6j/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="top-message" class="container">
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  Hi there!
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#top-message {
  z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modal bootstrap instead of alert. Modal is fixed position & size.

Read here: [Modal Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)